# Foreach inside array.map()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to map values to a new array. The problem is that the property that I'm mapping can either be a number or an array.

I have a problem when it comes to arrays, because my result is an associative array. My goal is to turn `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]` (see below) in to `[1,2,3,1,2,3]`. In other words; just make it a one dimensional array.

I've tried with a foreach loop inside the map(), without success. Any ideas?

```
var list = [{ foo: 1, bar: [1,2,3] }, { foo: 2, bar: [1,2,3] }];

var retArr = list.map(function (v) {

    return v.bar;

});

console.log(retArr); // [[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]
```

---

```
var list = [{ foo: 1, bar: [1,2,3] }, { foo: 2, bar: [1,2,3] }];

var retArr = list.map(function (v) {

    if($.isArray(v.bar)){

        $.each(v.bar, function(i, v){

            return v;
        });

    } else {

        return v.bar;
    }
});

console.log(retArr); // [undefined, undefined]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mck7N/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [jQuery's `map` function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/), you get array flattening automatically:

> The function can return [...] an array of values, which will be flattened into the full array

```
var retArr = $.map(list, function (v) {
    return v.bar;
});
```

---

In your second example, you get `[undefined, undefined]` as result because you are not returning a value from the callback. The return value of the `$.each` callback has no influence on the return value of the `.map` callback.

And `.map` wouldn't have helped you here, since you can only return one value from the callback. Instead you could just iterate over the array:

```
var retArr = [];

list.forEach(function (v) {
    if ($.isArray(v.bar)) {
        retArray.push.apply(retArray, v.bar);
    } 
    else {
        retArray.push(v.bar);
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). But since you are using jQuery anyway, using its map function is the easiest solution.

Comment: I had no idea that it was called "flatting". If I did, I probably would have found it :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without JQuery you can also flatten using `Array.reduce`:

```
var list = [{ foo: 1, bar: [1,2,3] }, { foo: 2, bar: [1,2,3] }]
   ,retArr = list.reduce(function (a,b) {
                 return a.concat(b.bar);
               },[]
           );
//=> retArr = [1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

Comment: In your first example the return value of map is never used so you should replace map with forEach which does the same but returns nothing. Also you can delete "return v;". In your second example you set the global variable retArr to [] and afterwards you call map. Global variables should be avoided if possible.

Comment: @SpiderPig: you're partly right. Changed the answer to using `Array.reduce`, which gives the OP a one liner.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `map` alone, since that would only return an array of arrays or numbers. Yet, you can flatten that into one array by using [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
var retArr = [].concat.apply([], list.map(function(v) { return v.bar; }));
```

If you used [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/), you can even shorten that into

```
var retArr = _.flatten(_.pluck(list, "bar"), true);
```